# The set of irrationals in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ has measure zero in $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that the set of discontinuities $D$ of Thomae's Function has measure zero using the complement of $D$, which is the set of points where $f$ is continuous, namely $([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I}) \times ([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I})$. I know that $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{I}$ does not have measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$. However, does $([0,1]\cap \mathbb{I})^2$ have measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No the irrationals dont have measure zero. So intersecting them with a non measure zero set gives you non measure zero set.

Comment: It's not too hard to prove that the complement has measure zero.

Comment: The product measure is defined such that $m(A \times B) = m(A) \cdot m(B)$.

Comment: @JonathanZ ahh the old enumerate the rationals and cover them by balls of the points plus and minus $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$ trick..

Comment: check @tychonovs-scholar answer for a detailed explanation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming we talk about the Lebesgue-measure:

Note that $\mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q})=0$, so using $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{I}$.
$$1= \mu([0,1])= \mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{R} )= \mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}) + \mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I}) = \mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I}) $$

So it follows that:

$\mu^2((\mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I})^2)=  (\mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I}))(\mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb{I})) \neq 0$.